# React-Native fetch through proxy

Tags: react-native, proxy, fetch-api

How can I set options in the `fetch` method of react-native to make a call to a webserver go through a proxy.

Currently I am using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) but this doesn't work.

After adding a host header to the fetch, I can make a request through charles-proxy but it doesn't work with squid. (`Error: invalid url`).

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Debugging, anonymizing requests? Have you been able to trace the requests by switching your app to debug mode (with Chrome dev tools)?

Comment: I think we need more detail. What are you trying to accomplish? How are you using charles? How are you using squid?

Comment: Sorry, away from the office for a little longer due to non-related issues, can't actually test it untill next week, meanwhile i'll get in touch with the rest of the developers team to see if they managed to get something. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you figure something out with regards to this? :)

Comment: Any solution found? I want to add proxy options in fetch

Comment: @SérgioReis Hey, how did you manage to solve it? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by installing `local-cors-proxy` globally and run it by

```
npm install -g local-cors-proxy
```

Start Proxy:

```
lcp --proxyUrl https://www.yourdomain.ie
```

Then in your client code, new API endpoint:

http://localhost:8010/proxy/movies/list

Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-cors-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Inside your package.json file that exists in your react project you can create a proxy like the following:

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

npm i free-proxy

package for creating proxy fetch request

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Hello You can use this module node-fetch(https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch) and set `agent` param for proxy,

For more details, you can also check this 
https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/79

Comment: This module is not compatible with React Native