# React-Native fetch through proxy with user and password

Tags: javascript, react-native, proxy, fetch-api

I'm trying to use `fetch` method to get/post data into a REST server (this is working), but some users of my app need to do this over a network(WiFi) with proxy authentication. I've searched this, I found a few answers, but no one have helped me, some doesn't work 'cause need the Node core modules (that isn't on React-Native packager), e.g: [https-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent).

Here I've found a similar question: [react-native-fetch-through-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674258/react-native-fetch-through-proxy), but axios don't supports proxy with user and password (I tried), and the unique answer doesn't worked for me, 'cause it need Node core modules (again).
I tried browserify to implement pieces of Node core, but the https-proxy-agent plugin can't see my JS files.